# SQL Query, FULL JOIN, performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table with properties for one person, the same person can have up to 18 different properties. The table looks like this:

```
Personid, Propertytype, Propertyvalue, Propertyname
```

I want to do an SQL query with FULL JOIN to get all the properties for one person into one row in the resultset.
I have done a query like this but I think it isn´t optimal if you think about respons time/performance.
In the database I have over 12 million people so it is a lot of datarows.

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (Information.PersonID),
  f.PersonName,
  f1.Property AS 'P1',
  f1.PropertyValue AS 'P1Value',
  f1.PropertyName AS 'P1Name',
  f2.Property AS 'P2',
  f2.PropertyValue AS 'P2Value',
  f2.PropertyName AS 'P2Name',
  ......
FROM Person f
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT
        PersonName,
        Property,
        PropertyValue,
        PropertyName
    FROM Person WHERE Property='P1'
    GROUP BY PersonName, Property, PropertyValue, PropertyName
) f1 ON f.PersonName=f1.PersonName
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT PersonName,
        Property,
        PropertyValue,
        PropertyName
    FROM Person WHERE Property='P2'
    GROUP BY PersonName, Property, PropertyValue, PropertyName
) f2 ON f.PersonName=f2.PersonName
    ....
INNER JOIN Information ON f.PersonName = Information.Name
```

Any advice how to do this query more effectively?

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? Please also add the table structure (fields and types)

Comment: What are you using, SQL Server, MySQL, DB2 etc.?

Comment: The table structure of **both** tables, Person and Information.

Comment: All of the columns in the table Person have the datatype nvarchar(50). In the table Information PersonId is a binary(16) and Name is nvarchar(100)

Comment: @Carin: I guess you mean all columns in table `Person` have the datatype nvarchar(50), **except** `PersonId, right?

Comment: Is it worth challenging why you need to denormalise the data set?  It strikes me that you already have the data is a suitable format for processing in SQL, and that client apps can easily pivot/denormalise this data on use.  What requirement is pushing you towards doing this within SQL?

Comment: Is it worth challenging that the data isn't normalised in the first place?

Comment: I Use this SQL query i SSIS to get data from a staging table to the destination table.

Answer (score 2):

You could select the rows you require then PIVOT the rows in to columns, 1 way would be to use a case statement in the select for each id.
This would reduce the number of scans against the person table.(as you would only have the scan the table once)
e.g:

```
SELECT personID,PersonName, max(p1val),max(p1name),max(p2val),max(p2name) ...etc
FROM
(
    SELECT Information.PersonID, 
    f.PersonName,
    case WHEN  Property ='P1' THEN PropertyValue ELSE NULL END as p1val,
    case WHEN  Property ='P2' THEN PropertyValue ELSE NULL END as p2val,
    case WHEN  Property ='P3' THEN PropertyValue ELSE NULL END as p3val,
    ....etc
    case WHEN  Property ='P1' THEN PropertyName ELSE NULL END as p1name,
    case WHEN  Property ='P2' THEN PropertyName ELSE NULL END as p2name,
    case WHEN  Property ='P3' THEN PropertyName ELSE NULL END as p3name,
    .....etc
    FROM Person f
)
GROUP BY personID,PersonName
```

Comment: this seems to be the fastest way to do the required task provided that properties are not duplicated, but this solution would handle that better than most other solutions

Comment: This seems to be the fastest, thanks a lot! But can you explain to me why to use max()?

Comment: The inner sql returns a single row for each property value e.g record 1: kevin 1 0 0 0 0 record 2: kevin 0 1 0 0 0 record 3: kevin 0 0 1 0 0 the max then returns a single row e.g kevin 1 1 1 0 0

Comment: But there is only one P1 property for every person. I have only used max() when there are several values for the same issue...if I don´t use max I can´t group by I guess..that´s why? Sorry but I don´t understand at first here :)

Comment: Exactly, I guess the use of max() does look a little odd, but it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Try using PIVOT. link to BOL here...http://link.phillip.pe/SQLPivot.

it translates multiple rows in a single column into multiple columns in a single row, e.g.

```
Person1, Left-Handed
Person1, Blue Eyes
Person2, Right-Handed
Person2, Brown Eyes
```

PIVOT to:

```
Person1, Left-Handed, Blue Eyes
Person2, Right-Handed, Brown Eyes
```

Comment: Is it possible to pivot 2 columns ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try, either working with `PIVOT`, or this:

```
SELECT 
    i.PersonID
  , i.PersonName
  , f1.Property AS 'P1'
  , f1.PropertyValue AS 'P1Value'
  , f1.PropertyName AS 'P1Name'

  , f2.Property AS 'P2'
  , f2.PropertyValue AS 'P2Value'
  , f2.PropertyName AS 'P2Name'

  ......
FROM 
  Information AS i
    LEFT JOIN Person AS f1
      ON  f1.PersonID = i.PersonId
      AND f1.Property = 'P1'
    LEFT JOIN Person AS f2
      ON  f2.PersonID = i.PersonId
      AND f2.Property = 'P2'
    ......
```

Comment: Ok, but is this faster than my solution...it seems to be the same response time!?

Comment: I'm not even convinced that the sub-queries from the OP's answer are necessary.  Just LEFT JOIN directly to Person each time?

Comment: You haven't told us the indexes you have on the tables.

Comment: @Dems: You are right. I did a similar thing yesterday which needed a GROUP BY in the subqueries. Corrected now.

Comment: I have no index on the Person table and the Informaion table I have index on PersonID.

Comment: I have tried the query above but for me it seems to takea as long as my original query!?

Comment: I would try by adding an index in table `Person` on `(Property, Personid)` or an index on `(Personid, Property)`. Or both and see with the execution plan which one is used.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with combination of `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` operations.

```
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT PersonName
        , Property [Prefix]
        , Property [ ]
        , PropertyValue [Value]
        , PropertyName [Name]
    FROM dbo.Person
)
, c AS
(
    SELECT b.PersonName, RTRIM(b.Prefix + b.Suffix) Field, b.Data
    FROM a
    UNPIVOT (Data FOR Suffix IN ([ ], [Value], [Name])) b
)
SELECT d.*
FROM c PIVOT (MIN(Data) FOR Field IN
    (
        [P1], [P1Value], [P1Name]
        , [P2], [P2Value], [P2Name]
        , [P3], [P3Value], [P3Name]
    )) d
```